# Why am I getting "Unable to find the checksum in the image" error?

Tags: linux, centos6

I'm using the CentOS_6.5_Final minimum install ISO. I would like to add `kernel-devel` to the Packages directory and rebuild the ISO for install.

First I loop mounted the source ISO and copied the data to a directory, added `kernel-devel` from the full DVD ISO using the same loop mount method.

Then I created the repodata from the `/mnt/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal` directory.

```
createrepo -p /mnt/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal/Packages/
```

The `repodata` is then place in `/mnt/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal/Packages/repodata`, so I moved it to `/mnt/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal/repodata` and replaced the original `/mnt/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal/repodata` with the new.

I then rebuilt the ISO.

```
genisoimage -o /tmp/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -V OSSA_01 -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -R -J -v -T /mnt/CentOS-6.5-x86_64-minimal/
```

Have I missed a step?

I'm not really looking to use the ks file right now. How do I make sure the image checksum is still valid? Is this what the GPG files in the ISO root are for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it, I was missing two hidden files..

`.discinfo` and `.treeinfo`